# Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for db

Tags: database, zend-framework, authentication, frameworks, zend-framework2

i have made a login form. 
I'm always getting this error in my controller that it was unable to fetch or create an instance for this db. i have read all the documentation about it and why this error occurs. i tried everything to fix this problem, but it is still not working. Can somebody help me. I'm using my database for other things and it can make a connection, but when i want to load the login page, i'm getting this error.

This is the code in my global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=music;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
        'username'       => 'root',
        'password'       => ''
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
            => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This is my controller

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        /** @var Mysqli $dbAdapter */
        $dbAdapter = $this->serviceLocator->get('db'); // This is where i'm getting the error from
        $db = $this->params('fms');

        $loginForm = new LoginForm();
        if ($this->request->isPost()) {

            $loginForm->setData($this->request->getPost());
            if ($loginForm->isValid()) {
                $auth = new AuthenticationService();
                $result = $auth->authenticate(new SqlAdapter(
                    $loginForm->get('email')->getValue(),
                    $loginForm->get('password')->getValue(),
                    $dbAdapter
            ));

                if ($result->getCode() == Result::SUCCESS) {
                    echo 'success';
                    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($this->url('')->fromRoute());
                } else {
                    echo 'fail';
                }

            }
        }

        $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
        return $this->view;

    }
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. Please somebody help me :)

Comment: ow and this is the error : 
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for db

Answer (score 2):

What you may need is this -

```
$dbAdapter = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

If you need the exact `db` array then do this -

```
$config = $this->serviceLocator->get('config');
$db_array = $config['db'];
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. it's working now. i thought that $this->serviceLocator->get('db'); where  the ->get('db') had to be the same name as :
return array(
    'db' => array(